# PHP, how to get every possible byte sequence in range?

Tags: php, byte

i want every possible byte sequence between range(x,y), like range(0,0xFFFF) would give me `00`...`FF`.`0000`.`0001`...`FFFF` ~

this works, but i suspect there's a much easier way to do it which escapes me, any suggestions?

```php
<?php
function incbinstring(string $str): string
{
    /*
    if(strlen($str)===0){
        return "\x00";
    }
    */
    $scanCurrent = strlen($str) - 1;
    while ($scanCurrent >= 0) {
        if ($str[$scanCurrent] !== "\xFF") {
            break;
        }
        --$scanCurrent;
    }
    if ($scanCurrent < 0) {
        // they're all \xFF... add new byte and all zeroes
        return str_repeat("\x00", strlen($str) + 1);
    }

    if ($scanCurrent !== strlen($str) - 1) {
        // preceeded by a bunch of \xFF\xFF\xFF , zero them out
        // ps, this can be optimized to a substr()+str_repeat()
        for ($i = strlen($str) - 1; $i > $scanCurrent; --$i) {
            $str[$i] = "\x00";
        }
    }
    // increment the first non-\xFF with 1
    $str[$scanCurrent] = chr(ord($str[$scanCurrent]) + 1);
    return $str;
}


$str = "\x00";
for ($i = 0; $i < 0xFFFF + 600; ++$i) {
    echo bin2hex($str),"\n";
    $str = incbinstring($str);
}
```

outputs, in part

```
00
01
02
03
04
05
06
07
(...)
f3
f4
f5
f6
f7
f8
f9
fa
fb
fc
fd
fe
ff
0000
0001
0002
0003
0004
(...)
fffb
fffc
fffd
fffe
ffff
000000
000001
000002
000003
000004
000005
000006
000007
```

Comment: If your code works, you may find posting it to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ more useful.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

  function counterHex ($fromHex, $toHex ) {
        $fromDec = hexdec($fromHex);
        $toHex = hexdec($toHex);
    
        for ($i = $fromHex; $i< $toHex; $i++){
            echo dechex($i) .", ";
        }
    }


   counterHex(1,'ff');
```

see: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d70d2766297c32039e01dd868e791b476bc92a87